# Serverless AWS-IAM Permissions

Tags: serverless, amazon-iam

Why does serverless needs iam:CreateRole permission to create LambdaExecution permission when I already attach a policy to the user which has full access to lambda?

Answer (score 1):

- Every AWS Lambda function needs permission to interact with other AWS infrastructure resources within your account. These permissions are set via an AWS IAM Role which the Serverless Framework automatically creates for each Serverless Service, and is shared by all of your Functions. The Framework allows you to modify this Role or create Function-specific Roles, easily. [Documentation](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam/)
- When building a serverless application, it’s important to assign each Lambda function a separate IAM role. This architecture ensures that each Lambda function is assigned least privilege permissions and is independent from other function’s permissions. It allows functions to evolve over time. As one function’s permissions are modified, they do not affect the other function’s permission scope. In [deep](https://medium.com/@glicht/serverless-framework-defining-per-function-iam-roles-c678fa09f46d)